# why history.goback() doesn't work with one click in react?

Tags: reactjs

I send the history as a prop from parent component to child and when I use history.goback() it doesn't work with one click and it needs a double click.
for example I am in Home page and I go to page one that has my MainMenu.js component and when I click on a button that calls history.goback() I need to double click on it to go to Home page. what is the problem?
my MainMenu.js:

```
export default function MainMenu (props) {

    const { history} = props;
    
    const handleBack = () => {
        history.goBack();
    }

    


    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <div className="main-menu-header">
              <div  mr-2 ml-1" onClick={handleBack}>
                            <svg className="float-right" style={{marginRight: -15}} xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                                <path fill="none" d="M24 0H0v24h24z" opacity="0.87"/>
                                <path  d="M6.616 2.99a1.249 1.249 0 0 1 1.77 0L16.7 11.3a1 1 0 0 1 0 1.41l-8.31 8.31a1.252 1.252 0 1 1-1.77-1.77L13.856 12l-7.25-7.25a1.246 1.246 0 0 1 .01-1.76z" transform="translate(0.764)"/>
                            </svg>

                        </div>
                           
            </div>

        </React.Fragment>
    )
}
```

and this is how I call this component in other components:

```
<MainMenu  history={props.history} />
```

Answer (score 1):

I actually solved my problem in this way. I'm not sure if it is a good answer or not but it solved my problem!

```
export default function MainMenu (props) {

    const { history} = props;

    useEffect(() => {
        if(history.action === 'POP'){
            history.goBack();
        }

    }, [history.action])
    
    const handleBack = () => {
        history.goBack();
    }

    


    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <div className="main-menu-header">
              <div  mr-2 ml-1" onClick={handleBack}>
                            <svg className="float-right" style={{marginRight: -15}} xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                                <path fill="none" d="M24 0H0v24h24z" opacity="0.87"/>
                                <path  d="M6.616 2.99a1.249 1.249 0 0 1 1.77 0L16.7 11.3a1 1 0 0 1 0 1.41l-8.31 8.31a1.252 1.252 0 1 1-1.77-1.77L13.856 12l-7.25-7.25a1.246 1.246 0 0 1 .01-1.76z" transform="translate(0.764)"/>
                            </svg>

                        </div>
                           
            </div>

        </React.Fragment>
    )
}
```

It guarantees the page will change to previous page.